# Finding nearest word from a character -Uima Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I need to find the nearest word from a character and that word should startswith that character.

For example:

**Sample Text:**

What you need is What you get **W**YG.

From the sample text,I need to find the nearest word startswith W.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
# W{REGEXP("W.*")};
```

or more general

```
DECLARE SameChar, SomeType;
CW{-> SomeType};
STRING firstChar;
SomeType<-{SomeType{-> firstChar = substring(CW.ct,0,1)};} # W{REGEXP(firstChar+".*")-> SameChar};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*